# Why do I get "404 not found" errors updating Ubuntu 11.04 (or other old versions)?

Tags: 11.04, apt, software-sources

Whenever I am trying to install **Compiz Config Settings Manager** through  *Synaptic Package Manager* ,

[image]

It shows the following error :

[image]

I have  tried it through the terminal. But it also  shows the following :

[image]

This type of error occurs for other software installation. How can I install  it success fully ?

Comment: 11.04 is [End of Life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) and no longer supported. This question is, therefore, [off-topic](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @chaskes Asking to do anything with 11.04 would be off topic but I think the question of "why is this happening" with an answer of "because it's EOL" is reasonable.

Comment: @poolie Thanks for your comment. I went back and forth on that question, but I'm not sure I was wrong. If EOL releases are off-topic, then "Why am I having problem X under an EOL?" is off-topic. But that said, I see that my (tired) comment was too curt and I should have explained what was happening and included advice about security and moving to a supported release.

Comment: @chaskes For me the deciding factor is that the error is so opaque: unless the user has been following it somewhere else there is no easy way for them to understand this means they must now upgrade, so we should answer it here.  I will change the title.

Comment: @poolie You're absolutely right on the larger issue and I failed to give good, welcoming guidance, something that annoys me when I see other people do it. ;) But I still think the definition of off-topic is clear in this case and the guidance is better in a comment.

Comment: ^^ Follow those instructions to sort out the issue!

Answer (score 0):

As chaskes says, you're seeing this because 11.04 has passed its end-of-life date and no more updates are available.  You should upgrade to (at least) 12.04 as soon as possible so that you get security updates.